# Постановка тире в предложении с составным именным сказуемым

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Возник вопрос, нужно ли ставить тире в предложении: "Серёжка, ива (–) это не цветок, а..."
В этом предложении столкнулись отрицательная частица НЕ и указательная частица ЭТО. Как применить правило постановки тире между подлежащим и сказуемым, выраженным существительным?
Заранее благодарю!!!

Answer (score 3):

Смело ставьте тире:

*Серёжка, ива – это не цветок, а дерево с серёжками.

Серёжка – это не цветок, а соцветие.*

Тире не ставится, если сказуемое выражено существительным с частицей ***не*** (и то не всегда), но...

> **Обратите внимание:** это не касается предложений со сказуемым-инфинитивом (например: *Чай пить – не дрова рубить*) и предложений со словами ЭТО, ВОТ, ЗНАЧИТ (например: *Аналогия – это не доказательство*).

Источник: [**Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым**](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_172) (Грамота.ру).

**Примеры из Нацкорпуса русского языка:**

*Ваша заливная рыба ― это не рыба…* (Эльдар Рязанов, Эмиль Брагинский. Ирония судьбы, или С легким паром. 1969)

*Ответ был прост: психотерапия ― это не рыба, а удочка* (Татьяна Трифоловская. «У всех всё хорошо, у меня одного все плохо» // «Детали мира». 2011).

*Филантропия ― это не любовь к ближнему в широком смысле слова* (А. А. Тарковский. Мартиролог. 1981).

*Поэтому их помощь ― это не любовь к нашему народу* (Никита Хрущев. Воспоминания. 1971).

*Ты должна понять, что марксизм ― это не религия, которая состоит из каких-то небылиц, а наука* (Владимир Войнович. Монументальная пропаганда // «Знамя». 2000).

*Деревня ― это не город. В деревне, если приглашают к столу, нельзя сразу соглашаться* (Фазиль Искандер. Чик чтит обычаи. 1967).

Answer (score 1):

• Для начала заглянем в словарь:
[**цветок**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA), -тка; ***мн.*** цветы и (*спец.*) цветки; ***м.***
**1.** Часть растения; орган размножения, обычно имеющий вид венчика из лепестков, окружающих пестик с тычинками.
**2.** ***мн.:*** цветы, -ов. Травянистое растение, имеющее в пору цветения яркую (нередко и ароматную) головку или соцветие.

• Да, в этом предложении действительно всё столкнулось, смешалось, и не только *не* и *это*.
*Серёжка, ива — это не цветок, а...*
При такой пунктуации, когда запятая стоит после слова "Серёжка", оно воспринимается как обращение (его можно исключить из предложения).
Остается: *Ива — это не цветок, а...*

Ни один нормальный человек не назовет иву (высотой до 30 метров!) цветком (в любом значении). Это противоречит здравому смыслу.
Предложение из вопроса должно быть таким: ***Серёжка ивы — это не цветок, а...***
Или таким: *Серёжка (ива) — это не цветок, а...*

• Подзабылась уже ботаника... Но интересно стало, "поназаглядывала" еще...

> Типы простых ботрических соцветий:
> <...>
> **серёжка** — поникающий колос, опадает целиком с осью соцветия, обычно несет однополые цветки (ива, тополь).

• А тире, конечно же, ставится (Александр привел в своем ответе правило и классные примеры; не буду повторяться, просто поддержу).
Оборванное предложение может быть таким:
*Серёжка ивы — это не цветок, а соцветие, которое называется "поникающий колос".*

[Соцветия](https://foxford.ru/wiki/biologiya/sotsvetiya)
[Ботрическое соцветие](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/bse/70775/%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5)

P. S. Все-таки дополню ответ правилом из ПАС (в нем есть нужный нам пример с *не*).

> [**§ 11.**](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=106#pp106) Тире ставится перед сказуемым, присоединяемым к подлежащему словами *вот, это: «Уважение к минувшему — вот черта, отличающая образованность от дикости», — сказал когда-то Пушкин* (Расп.); *Пушкиногорье — **это не только памятник** историко-литературный, **это** и своеобразный ботанический и зоологический **сад**, замечательный памятник природы* (Гейч.)...

Comment: Римма, спасибо за поддержку! Вот о чём хочу сказать. Ситуации бывают разные. Например, маленького ребёнка спрашивают, какие цветы он знает, и он пока путается в огромном разнообразии природы и названий. Каштан – что это? Фрукт, зверь, дерево, одежда, инструмент? Не узнаешь, не вспомнишь – не ответишь. Сомневаюсь, что автор допустил ошибки именно в ключевом предложении своего грамотно написанного вопроса (хотя я тоже думал о варианте "Серёжка ив**ы**..."). Но Екатерина молчит, никак не реагирует...

Comment: А за экскурс в ботанику, безукоризненность оформления (она мне всегда по душе) и правило с нужным примером – конечно, плюс!

Comment: Ну-у... Это *мое* впечатление от предложения. Чес-слово, воспринимается как обращение. Хотя вопрос-то, собственно, о тире. Но — хотелось как лучше. P. S. А вот оформление с картинками в БСЭ (http://bse.uaio.ru/BSE/97/socvet.htm): Соцветия: 1 - кисть (иван-чай); 2 - щиток (груша); 3 - колос (подорожник); 4 - серёжка (ива, 4а - пестичная, 4б - тычиночная)... Еще: простые соцветия:  сережка (ива, грецкий орех)... P. P. S. Похвала — это всегда приятно. Спасибо, *Стрельчик*! (Или *Стрелечик*?)

Comment: Так меня еще не называли :)).  Дык я и говорю, что, возможно, обращаются к ребенку, что это нормальное предложение (реакция на неправильный ответ познающего мир). Ну уже не суть...